# Trying to check the value of a cell and compare it to another value to see if it matches(Google Script)

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to creating a booking system, and as of now I am going to allow my user to insert their name and then check if there is a value. But whenever I try to simply accomplish this by using if( m == 'string) it thinks that all of the empty spaces are strings which results in everything saying booked.

```
Function checkifBooked(name)
{
var string ='BOOKED';
var string2 ='FREE';

if(typeof name == 'string')
{
return string;
}
else{
return string2;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the value of an empty cell you get an empty string `''`, which is still a string.  Thus, your `if` always evaluates to True.

In javascript, an empty string evaluates to false, so you can test the string directly.

try:

```
if(name)
```

Or if you prefer to be more explicit, you could check the type of name, then check it's length.

```
if(typeof(name) == 'string' && name.length > 0)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! that fixed the issue

Comment: Happy to help! To accept the answer and mark it correct, click the checkmark on the left hand side.